# Why doesn't my 2D array displaying properly and doesn't display input

Tags: java, arrays

i want it to display the 2d Array and then replace parts of the                          array with  user input but it doesn't. Please help because I can't tell what is    wrong with it.

Now it doesn't display properly

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class d {

public static void printBoard(char[][]board) {
System.out.println("    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
    String ab = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    System.out.println(ab.charAt(row) + " |");
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            board[row][col] = 'z';
            System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
        }
}
}

public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
char[][] board = new char[10][10];

printBoard(board);
System.out.println(" board number");
int a= k.nextInt();
System.out.println(" board number");
int x= k.nextInt();
board[a][x] = 'x';
    printBoard(board);
}
}
```

Comment: You print it before you populate it. And you only populate `a` and `x`. What output did you expect?

Comment: what you expect to replace? there are nothing in the array before `board[a][x] = 'x'`.

Comment: Ok i've changed it now but i cant seem to get it right. Could you please explain to me what I should be doing @ElliottFrisch? Im pretty confuse on how I should be doing this now. Help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Initialize your Array

You currently declare an array `board`, but you only assign one `char` based on user input. Start by filling the `board` with space. Something like,

```
static char[][] createBoard(int x, int y) {
    char[][] board = new char[x][y];
    for (char[] row : board) {
        Arrays.fill(row, ' ');
    }
    return board;
}
```

#### Print a newline when done with the current row

If the columns are intended to line up, then print the newline when finished with the `row` you're iterating. Also, you don't want to initialize your array in a method for printing it. Something like,

```
public static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
    String ab = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    System.out.println("    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        System.out.print(ab.charAt(row) + " |"); // <-- not a newline.
        for (char ch : board[row]) {
            System.out.printf("%c ", ch);
        }
        System.out.println(); // <-- done with the current line.
    }
}
```

Finally, create `board` in `main` with something like,

```
char[][] board = createBoard(10, 10);
```